# how to optimize a mongodb `distinct` query with a date constraint?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, query-optimization

given a collection called `probe` which grows by 11 million records per week and contains a record of vulnerability exploit probes that include a `date` property and a `source.ip` property, ie:

```js
{
  _id: ObjectId('64943e2001000100160b843e'),
  date: '2023-06-22T12:27:12Z',
  source: {
    ip: '217.17.230.18',
    port: 56882
  },
  target: {
    ip: '88.198.64.58',
    port: 22
  }
}
```

what type of index would improve the performance of a query which selects distinct source.ip where date is greater than a variable date? ie (node.js):

```js
export const recent = async (since) => (
  await client.db('cichlid').collection('probe').distinct(
    'source.ip',
    {
      date: {
        $gte: since.toISOString().replace('.000Z', 'Z')
      }
    }
  )
);
```

the query is run from an aws lambda behind api gateway which limits it to a 30 second timeout. there are currently no indexes (other than the automatically created ones) on the collection and it has started timing out as the collection size has grown.

- do i need a compound index for both fields (`date`, `source.ip`)?
- should i create a simple index on `date`?
- should i create a simple index on `source.ip`?

compass gives me a choice of index types (asc, desc, 2dsphere, text). since the date filter is generally *now() minus 1 hour*, i assume desc is appropriate for that field and text might be appropriate for the ip address. but i'm only guessing...
[image]

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551 and [db.collection.createIndex](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/)

Comment: You should **never** store date/time values as string, it's a design flaw. Store always proper `Date` objects, it will also solve your issue with milliseconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i went ahead and created 3 indexes:

- compound: date (desc) and source.ip (text)
- simple: date (desc)
- simple: source.ip (text)

compass shows that only the simple date (desc) index gets used. the distinct source.ip query went from taking 44 seconds to complete, to 500 milliseconds. i guess this answers the question.
[image]

in this particular case, the index needs to be on the filter constraint field and this increases performance by a factor of 88x.